# Writing verification steps for PL/SQL Sequence

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sequence

I am writing the launch plan for one of my code. In which, for each step i have to write a verification step which will tell if the deployment/change has been made properly. Like if there is an alter table command to add a new column then as a verification, I would be using **select column_name from table** as verification step.

I am looking for a verification step for my sequence script. My sequence scripts is dropping the old sequence and re-creating it with *initial* value changed. lets say if my last sequece was on 10071 - the new sequece would start from 100710.

I wrote the following query

```
SELECT LAST_NUMBER 
  FROM all_sequences 
 WHERE sequence_name = 'SEQNAME';
```

Now, my question is, would that give the last number of my new sequence or the old sequence?

P.S:
I can't use sequence NextValue - it would cause the system to miss 1 number and will mess up the whole system. However, I am open for the options in which my *next_value* can be utlizied, automatically.

Comment: simple enough to try on a dummy sequence...

Comment: Why would missing a number mess up the whole system?  Sequences are not gap-free.  If you need gap-free values, you should not be using sequences.  If you can't safely select the sequence.nextval, I would be very concerned that you are using sequences improperly and that your application is going to encounter problems in the future.

Comment: @Randy: I guess i mentioned that the scenario is that this sequence is being deployed. I have tested it on dummy table .. but its updated value has to be test in production

Comment: @JustinCave: emm, lets put it this way, that the system which is reading from DB is expecting "continuous" values. if there is a gap in value then it would be problem in "reporting".

Comment: @alee - Do you understand that if you're using a sequence, there will inevitably be gaps in the values that are inserted?  And that reporting will inevitably encounter problems?  It sounds like you have an underlying problem that makes sequences unsuitable for your system.  If you truly need continuous, gap-free values, you'd either have to compute them on the fly (i.e. using dense_rank analytic function in a view) or you'd need to serialize inserts.

Comment: Now, my question is, would that give the last number of my new sequence or the old sequence? ... just make a new sequence and try your query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, my question is, would that give the last number of my new sequence or the old sequence?

Err ... Why not just try it as suggested by Randy in the comments ?

```
SQL> !cat /tmp/sql.sql

create sequence foo start with 10;

select min_value, max_value, increment_by, last_number
from user_sequences
where sequence_name = 'FOO';

drop sequence foo;

create sequence foo start with 20;

select min_value, max_value, increment_by, last_number 
from user_sequences 
where sequence_name = 'FOO';

drop sequence foo;

SQL> @/tmp/sql

Sequence created.


 MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE INCREMENT_BY LAST_NUMBER
---------- ---------- ------------ -----------
         1 1.0000E+28            1          10


Sequence dropped.


Sequence created.


 MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE INCREMENT_BY LAST_NUMBER
---------- ---------- ------------ -----------
         1 1.0000E+28            1          20


Sequence dropped.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

LAST_NUMBER will not be accurate if your sequence uses a cache (which is the default)

```
SQL> CREATE SEQUENCE seq_1;

Sequence created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT seq_1.nextval FROM dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         1

SQL>
SQL> SELECT sequence_name,
  2         min_value,
  3         last_number
  4  FROM user_sequences
  5  WHERE sequence_name = 'SEQ_1';

SEQUENCE_NAME                   MIN_VALUE LAST_NUMBER
------------------------------ ---------- -----------
SEQ_1                                   1          21

SQL>
SQL> SELECT seq_1.nextval FROM dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         2

SQL>
SQL> SELECT sequence_name,
  2         min_value,
  3         last_number
  4  FROM user_sequences
  5  WHERE sequence_name = 'SEQ_1';

SEQUENCE_NAME                   MIN_VALUE LAST_NUMBER
------------------------------ ---------- -----------
SEQ_1                                   1          21

SQL>
```